# prevent duplicate data from Excel to db via Oledb c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, excel

I Have a excel and I want Upload only four columns of that to SQL Table with a button. 
The problem is when I repeat click the button all of that data will be duplicated but I Don't want that. I want only new data to be update.
My query:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int UserID;
        int InsuID;
        string Result;
        int Year;

        //** مسیر فایل اکسل**
        String ExcelPath = @"D:\Insu_lab.xlsx";

        //** کانکشن به آفیس**
        OleDbConnection mycon = new OleDbConnection("Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = " + ExcelPath + "; Extended Properties=Excel 8.0; Persist Security Info = False");
        mycon.Open();
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select * from [Sheet1$]", mycon);
        OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {

            UserID = Convert.ToInt32(dr[0].ToString());
            InsuID = Convert.ToInt32(dr[1].ToString());
            Result = dr[2].ToString();
            Year = Convert.ToInt32(dr[3].ToString());

            savedata(UserID, InsuID, Result, Year);
            Label1.Text = "اطلاعات با موفقیت در  دیتابیس ذخیره شد";

        }
    }

    private void savedata(int UserID, int InsuID, string Result, int Year)
    {
        String query = "insert into tbl_Result(UserID,InsuID,Result,Year) values(" + UserID + ",'" + InsuID + "','" + Result + "','" + Year + "') ";
        String mycon = "Data Source=MC6082; Initial Catalog=Insurance; Integrated Security=true";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(mycon);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = query;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

Comment: Please make your question more clear: Do you want new data to be *added* or an updated file also *update* existing data.

You propably missing some unique key, maybe userID and InsuID?

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1: When you `clicked`on `button`, that(`button`) disable the button.

```
Button1.disable = true;
```

When export ended:

```
Button1.disable = false;
```

Solution 2: you can use from jquery ajax in this part.

Comment: Thank You,would you distribute about Solution 2?